# Unable to convert list to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am having lists of data which I read from a list of text files in a directory. My code looks like this:

```py
# reads all the files in the directory and saves them into a list
ham_path = 'C:/Users/Downloads/easy_ham/*'
ham = []
files = glob.glob(ham_path)
for file in files:
    f = open(file, 'r', encoding="latin-1")
    data = f.readlines()
    spam.append(data)
    f.close()
```

Similarly I have a different list named spam.

I want to create a pandas DataFrame with these columns:

1. messages = ham and spam list data
2. type = spam for spam data or ham for ham list data

The lists created are perfect, but when I try to create a DataFrame it throws an error.
All I want is an Excel view like pandas DataFrame with the above mentioned columns.

I am new to Python and pandas.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please show how the lists look like and also how do you want the output to be. Also consider editing this post, the structure is quite unclear and you're using wrong the code blocks... Thank you. Mention me when finished to help you out.

Comment: Please take a minute to see to to properly format both your code and your text. Plus, question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Hi @JonathanSánchez , my list is basically a list of e-mails  saved in a text format in my local which i am reading using the above code from a directory called spam,thier are about 1000 files in it, the text file are generally in an email format containg special charecters and spaces . If you want me to send you a copy of the emial , i can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    hamPath='C:/Users/Downloads/mailData/easy_ham/*'
    ham=[]
    files=glob(hamPath)
    for file in files:
     inner_ham=[]
     inner_ham.append(open(file,'r',encoding="latin-1").read())
     inner_ham.append('ham')
     ham.append(inner_ham)
   df_ham=pd.DataFrame(ham,columns=['messages','type'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

with open(file) as f:
    my_list = [line.strip() for line in f]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
```

You can access the particular columns with something like

`df['Column']` if your list contains any columns

Comment: the file I am reading a an exact copy of an email from a folder containg 1000 similar format files and yes with special characters  and spaces, in your code you are each reading line of the whole messages and saving it as a single elemet in a list, what I want is to save the complete file as a single element in a list, my code for reading and appending it to a list is working fine all I want is an excel like structure of the the list